# How to divide Equity in a co-owned home?

Tags: house-sale

Five years ago my girlfriend and I purchased a home.  I put down $65,000 of my own money    The rest came from our joint account ( around 20k).  We have since broken up  and have about $150,000 in equity.  I told her I wanted 70k from  The initial sale to cover my down payment  and the rest of the equity would be split 50-50.  She is being difficult and trying to  tell me since she made more money she has more equity into the home than I do.  Is this true?  Is she entitled to more of the equity because she made more?

Comment: If the joint account was not deposited in to in a 50/50 manner and there was no agreement made beforehand I'd say she has a valid argument.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I'm not even sure that she has made more money than me.  She's been out of work for the last 18 months.  She also has two children that aren't mine that also cost money. But no we did not have any agreement

Comment: @quid - a valid argument about what? If the place is sold the creditors (mortgage) should  be paid off first, then the OP should get his $65K and any remainder should be split. Unless she can prove that she had been making more repayments than him, then she has no argument.

Comment: @Victor, this person is asking for $70k plus half the remaining net proceeds after sale.  I'd say if she did indeed pay in more than 50% of the payment (via larger contribution in to the join account) she has an argument regarding the additional $5k on the down and the even split on the remaining net sale proceeds.

Comment: @victor@quid- so there was no agreement, why would it favor her? If she thought she was going to be paying more, then shouldn't she have  documented that from the start?

Comment: @Jdub5084, I'm not saying she's right.  I'm saying, absent a written agreement, there's space to argue (though, the argument may actually work out in your favor).  Flip the question around, if you were going to request $5k more than the down shouldn't you have documented that from the start?  You're both requesting something and there's room to argue.

Comment: Guys you make good points. But absent an agreement they are just opinions, no more or less valid than the OP or his ex.

Comment: @quid - which is why I said that without any proof the OP should get $65K and any remainder split. However, if the OP does not have proof of this $65K payment then that is up in the air as well. There is no valid argument without proof to back it up.

Comment: @Victor, so we agree that both sides have an argument.

Comment: No @quid, you said the girlfriend has a valid argument! Maybe you have seen her proof? What I said is there is no valid argument without proof. Either side can say what they want, but without proof it is worthless.

Comment: @Victor, She does have a valid argument because OP is requesting more than his downpayment (before splitting the net proceeds) without any proof or documentation that he would be entitled to it.  She is saying no to his request (rightfully), and contending that she may have, in fact, been paying more than half of the mortgage due to her income.  So both sides need to start looking at bank statements and/or try to come to an agreement. You came up with a totally different settlement than the one proposed in the question because, the reality is that OP is requesting $5k more than the down.

Comment: @Quid- I'm asking for 70k because 65k came from my account, 20k came from our account. I'm conceding 15K of it was hers in 5K if it was mine. I thought that was pretty reasonable if not in favor of her

Comment: @Jdub5084, you should add that to your question because that's not how it reads currently.  What you're saying now is the down payment was $85,000, $70k from you and $15k from her.  The question doesn't indicate there is any amount being conceded to her.

Answer (score 4):

**There is no standard way to divide property under these circumstances.**

This is why lawyers recommend agreeing how property will be divided up front, and why they make so much money sorting out issues like this when couples divorce. Incidentally, you don't say which country you are in, but in many countries if you have lived together for five years, **your breakup can be treated like a divorce**, legally speaking. If you can't agree on how to divide the property, the courts will be involved.

You are faced with a choice. Either find some way to come to an agreement you can both accept, or hire lawyers and argue it out in court. You might want to consider finding someone to act as mediator who will help you to come to an agreement. Professional mediation services exist, or you could consider a person you both respect and with the skills to do this.

Comment: +1 a mediator is probably a good idea with this much money involved.

Comment: The OP may want to get independent legal advice from a lawyer, before suggesting this as a solution to his ex-girlfriend.

Answer (score -1):

> Is she entitled to more of the equity because she made more?

No.  Equity should be determined by how much each paid.  But she is entitled to more of the equity if she paid more.  And that may be what she is saying.  That she contributed more to the household's finances than you did.

If you always paid the mortgage out of the joint account, you could presumably go back and look at the account to find out how much each of you contributed to it.  That would give you a reasonable split for the remainder of the equity after your initial investment.  If you both put your entire paychecks into the joint account every time, then it will be the same as the ratio of what you each made.  That would also make sense for splitting up whatever remains in that account.

While you're doing that, you may want to ask for more for your original $65,000.  By my calculation, if your mortgage was 3.5%, that $65,000 saved the household more than $12,000 in interest that became equity instead.  So you could reasonably bump your return on the initial investment up to $77,000 while making the concession on the rest of the equity.

This is just a suggestion for a framework for splitting the equity.  If you can agree on a split, it will almost certainly be easier than going to a mediator or court.